# Couchbase XDCR on Openstack

Tags: nosql, couchbase, openstack

Having received no replies on the Couchbase forum after nearly 2 months, I'm bringing this question to a broader audience.

I'm configuring CB Server 2.2.0 XDCR between two different Openstack (Essex, eek) installations. I've done some reading on using a DNS FQDN trick in the couchbase-server file to add a `-name ns_1@(hostname)` value in the start() function. I've tried that with absolutely zero success. There's already a flag in the start() function that says  `-name 'babysitter_of_ns_1@127.0.0.1'` so I don't know if I need to replace that line, comment it out, or keep it. I've tried all 3 of those; none of them seemed to have any positive effect.

The FQDNs are pointing to the Openstack floating_ip addresses (in amazon-speak, the "public" ones). Should they be pointed to the fixed_ip addresses (amazon: private/local) for the nodes?  Between Openstack installations, I'm not convinced pointing to an unreachable (potentially duplicate) class-C private IP is of any use.

When I create a remote cluster reference using the floating_ip address to a node in the other cluster, of course it'll create the cluster reference just fine. But when I create a Replication using that reference, I always get one of two distinct errors: `Save request failed because of timeout` or `Failed to grab remote bucket 'bucket' from any of known nodes.`

What I think is happening is that the Openstack `floating_ip` isn't being recognized or translated to its `fixed_ip` address prior to surfing the cluster nodes for the bucket. I know the  `-name ns_1@(hostname)` modification is supposed to fix this, but I wonder if anyone has had success configuring XDCR between Openstack installations that may be able to provide some tips or hacks.

I know this "works" in AWS. It's my belief that AWS uses some custom DNS enabling queries to return an instance's fixed_ip ("private" IP) when going between availability zones, possibly between regions.  There may be other special sauce in AWS that makes this work.

Answer (score 2):

This blog post on aws Couchbase XDCR replication should help! There are quite a few steps so I won't paste them all here.

http://blog.couchbase.com/cross-data-center-replication-step-step-guide-amazon-aws

Comment: Thanks for the note. That post is exactly what I've tried; it helps specifically for AWS.  Unfortunately, AWS and Openstack (at least, the Essex relesase) are not the same secret sauce at the network layer.  AWS can fetch private IPs across availability zones through DNS, which is why FQDN works for AWS, but Openstack cannot.